# Welche Deklination folgt auf „alles“?

Tags: noun, article, declension

Wie beugt man Substantive nach *alles*?

Welche der folgenden ist korrekt

> Ich bin von alles Deutsche fasziniert
>
> Ich bin von alles Deutschem fasziniert
>
> Ich bin von allem Deutschen fasziniert

Comment: Korrekt ist in dem Beispiel der Dativ, also die dritte Variante: "...von allem Deutschen..."

Comment: Dass der Dativ richtig ist wahr dem OP wohl klar, die Frage war, wie der Dativ hier richtig gebildet wird.

Comment: Der Fall wird hier nicht von "alles", sondern von "von" regiert.

Answer (score 3):

Das Wort *alles* kann sowohl Indefinitpronomen wie auch ein bestimmter Artikel sein; siehe dazu die entsprechende Seite auf [Canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/InflectionRules/FRegeln-P/Pron-Indef/Pron-all3.html). Als bestimmter Artikel löst *alles* die [schwache Deklination](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Adjektiv/Deklinationstyp/Schwach.html) aus – wie *das.*

> Alles Deutsche ist spannend.
>
> Der Klang alles Deutschen ist interessant.
>
> Ich bin von **allem Deutschen** fasziniert.
>
> Ich mag alles Deutsche.

Da es sich bei *das Deutsche* um ein substantiviertes Adjektiv handelt, wird es entsprechend flektiert. Außerdem löst *von* den Dativ aus.

Die einzig richtige Form ist also die letzte.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments:

> Ich bin von allem Deutschen fasziniert.

"von all **dem** Deutschen fasziniert sein"